# Sonar scanner - Source not in SCM - assign new issues

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 5.6.6 to scan source not managed with a SCM (like GIT or SVN).
But with our "in-house" tool, we know who made the last changes (similarly than the last committer in Git or SVN).

is it possible; in sonar properties file used to make the analysis; to give the developer name (same than into Sonar) that change the source to have new issue automatically assigned ?

I did find the information here :https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by specifying any parameters. You have to create your own [SCM provider](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+an+SCM+Provider) and next add a parameter to SonarScanner:

```
-Dsonar.scm.provider=custom-id
```